# FileSystemWatcher distorts filename 

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I'm using `FileSystemWatcher` to detect *.docx* files. Files are detected when open, however the filename is always "corrupted".

3 examples :

1. If my file name is : *2711111.docx*, the file name recived in `FileSystemWatcher.Changed` is : *~$711111.docx*.
2. For file : *2711111_1.docx* I get the filename : *~$11111_1.docx*
   I can't guess what my filename will be, so I am looking for a general solution.
3. For file contains/starts with a letter, it doesn't happen.

Here's my code

```
MyPath = String.Format(@"C:\Users\{0}\NRPortbl\ACTIVE\{1}\"", 
         Public.UserName, Public.UserName);

FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(MyPath))
{
    Public.Logger.Error(
        String.Format
            ("Path of folders {0} not found", MyPath));
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
        String.Format(
            "There was a problem loading {0} " + 
            "NRPortbl libraray, contact administrator", Public.UserName));
    return;
}
watcher.Path = MyPath;
watcher.Filter = "*.Docx";                                                      
watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);                       
watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDeleted);
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;  ... 
public void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)  {...}
```

Help will be much appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: is onchanged getting fired only once? or multiple times when opening a docx file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design for Microsoft Word.  It creates a hidden file when a user opens a document.  That file records the user name so that when somebody else tries to open the same document, they'll get a decent message that tells them what user currently has the document opened for editing.

The file name of that hidden file is the original file name with the first two characters replaced with `~$`

You don't normally see this file when looking at the directory with Explorer because it has the FileAttributes.Hidden attribute turned on.  Surely you want to ignore these files as well, use the FileInfo.Attributes property to filter them.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, if i define this folder to be hidden, then everytime i open a file, i wouldn't reach "Create" function, isn't there a way to figuer out the "real" name of the file ? i tried doing :             
System.IO.FileInfo info = new System.IO.FileInfo(MyPath);
            info.Attributes = FileAttributes.Hidden;

Comment: I can't make much sense of that comment.  You certainly wouldn't want to *set* the hidden attribute, only *test* it.

Comment: hi, it's just that whenever i need the file's name, i get the file name with ~$, and so, i want to "locate" the original file name, as shown to human eyes, in order to track it.

Comment: What would be the point of that?  All you know is that somebody has opened a document.  Nothing got created or changed.  Iterating the directory and looking for a filename match (minus the first 2 characters) is otherwise the obvious approach.

Answer (score 4):

Subscribe to a few more events, such as renaming, and output their filenames.

I suspect what you're seeing are temporary filenames which get changed to the actual filename with a rename.

Answer (score 2):

Untested code, but I remember myself doing the trick like this before..

First of all when you open a file or save a file, `OnChanged` event will (hopefully) fire multiple times. So you can see that at one point you get the right filename. To see that, you can use the file exists function and some other techniques. Like this or so:

```
public void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) 
{
     if (e.FullPath.Contains("~$")) //to avoid the corruption you are talking about.
         return;                    //or better handling - trivial

     if (!File.Exists(e.FullPath)) //to avoid some temp files that need not be visible
         return;                   //but happens with doc files. 

     //got the file e.FullPath
}
```

In case you dont get the required file, you can subscribe for another event, the rename event.